# Generic Type of a Generic Type in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface

```
public interface BWidgetObject<T> {
}
```

and I want to use this interface to create a new generic interface based on this type:

```
public interface BDataList<BWidgetObject> {}
```

The former gives a warning that the type `T` is hidden. The following give a compiler error:

```
public interface BDataList<BWidgetObject<T>> {}
```

How can I express `BWidgetObject<T>` as type parameter for `BDataList`?

Comment: The answer depends on what the type parameter of `BDataList` is suppposed to represent ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with:

```
public interface BDataList<T extends BWidgetObject<?>> {}
```

Here we're specifying the the type `T` will be a `BWidgetObject` of a type we don't actually care about (and that's why we use a wildcard). We only care about `T` and the fact it will be a subtype of `BWidgetObject`.

Comment: Is there a way to define the Type of BWidgetObject instead of a wild card?

Comment: Yes. You can replace the wildcard with whatever actual type you want, however you should be aware that this will make your generic parameter `T` less flexible

Comment: I tried public interface BDataList<T extends BWidgetObject<V>> {} but it did not work?

Comment: If `V` is another type parameter, you have to do `BDataList<T extends BWidgetObject<V>, V>`

Comment: Then I get ``Bound mismatch: The type V is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends BaseEntity> of the type BWidgetObject<T>```

Comment: Could you pleas post the correct form in your answer?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly you want to do. What is `V`? Is it a type or is it a type parameter? Does it have bounds?

Comment: public interface BWidgetObject<V> {
}

Comment: public interface BWidgetObject<V extends Dto> { }

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic *bound*:

```
public interface BDataList<T extends BWidgetObject<?>> {}
```

Or if you need to type the widget explicitly, you need to create another sub-interface:

```
public interface BWidgetDataList<T> extends BDataList<BWidgetObject<T>> {}
```

Comment: W shouldn't use generic type without parametrizing it, so better public interface BDataList<T extends BWidgetObject<?>> {}